# Glassfish cannot find imported class

Tags: java, glassfish

I have a small webservice program in which I need to import JSONObject from external jar. While trying to deploy the webservice, the Glassfish couldn't find the imported class (from external jar), but things look fine in IDE.

I tried to look into the log and found this :

> [2017-11-17T16:22:49.429+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1510932169429] [levelValue: 900] [[
>     StandardWrapperValve[MyApplication]: Servlet.service() for servlet MyApplication threw exception
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.JSONObject

Can someone help me ?

Comment: have you verified that the .jar permissions allow you to execute it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the library to your Glassfish directory too. Otherwise Glassfish will not find it.

Add the `.jar` file to `<GLASSFISH_DIR>\glassfish\domain\domain1\lib` and then restart your Glassfish.